# Is there an online animation repository I can use to communicate my ideas?

Tags: animation, resource-recommendations, mobile, games

I am currently working on a mobile based game. There are a lot assets involved and an equal amount of animations (buttons, graphical elements, etc.).

Now the real problem is that getting the exact idea in my head across to the developers is proving to be quite difficult. To put it simply, it is difficult to make them imagine what I am imagining. I have tried to recreate certain basic effects using after effects, but that is proving to be too time consuming!

Is there a repository over the internet where I can see different kinds of animations? I have gone through [Capptivate](https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcapptivate.co%2F&ei=Y-OdVMa1MYfyPJrqgPgP&usg=AFQjCNEKfi35iwsxyPvgwGYtYbKqMFBQhw&sig2=EsthrRBWbwsPzkvutYrt5g&bvm=bv.82001339,d.ZWU). Also seen [Dribble](https://dribbble.com/) etc for the same. I admit that these sites have helped me a bit, but they are too wide spread in their content.

Please, if anyone knows a place where they have a gallery of different kinds of animations (mobile based preferably), let me know! It would be of a great help!

Comment: Platform please?  Only CSS, JavaScript, SVG, Unity, Android-Java, iOS-ObjectiveC...?

Comment: Hey Tom.. Its for Android platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to share simple animations you could maybe use some of these **CSS/JS** libraries demos. Most have the common transition effects, but there are some advanced ones too.

Animations that are really easy lo find on the demo:

- [**CSS Animation Cheat Sheet**](http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/)
- [**Bounce.js**](http://bouncejs.com/)

Other CSS animation libraries:

- [Animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)
- [Animo.js](http://labs.bigroomstudios.com/libraries/animo-js)
- [Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)